# Elastic Search 2.3.3 heap used too high，jvm old gen percent 100%，not crash

Tags: elasticsearch

Elasticsearch version:2.3.3

Plugins installed: []

JVM version:1.8_091

OS version:linux-3.10.101kernel

Description of the problem including expected versus actual behavior:

We deploy 12 es nodes in 3 machine. After we insert 1 billion record into es cluster and Meanwhile,we also send query request to es for search. After 3 day passed, es's jvm heap FGC frequently.the node's jvm gcutil looks like that: total 3.8GB for ES_HEAP, 2.6GB for jvm's old gen, and the old gen used is 100%.
We stop all write and read request,but the old gen used could not decrease. The old gen used is 100%.
We clear cache of es,but the old gen used only decrease to 96%.

#### Steps to reproduce:

1. use config see below
2. do insert and query
3. after data increase to 1 billion, heap used become 100%.

#### Provide logs (if relevant):

> [2017-02-05 11:58:38,221][INFO ][monitor.jvm ] [xxx]
> [gc][old][1332853][268813] duration [5s], collections [1](http://discuss.elastic.co/t/2-3-3-heap-used-too-high-jvm-old-gen-percent-100-not-crash/74582)/[5.1s],
> total [5s]/[17.2h], memory [3.8gb]->[2.8gb]/[3.8gb], all_pools
> {[young] [1gb]->[166.8mb]/[1gb]}{[survivor]
> [130.7mb]->[0b]/[136.5mb]}{[old] [2.6gb]->[2.6gb]/[2.6gb]} [2017-02-05
> 12:04:39,450][INFO ][monitor.jvm ] [xxx] [gc][old][1333207][268917]
> duration [6.2s], collections [1](http://discuss.elastic.co/t/2-3-3-heap-used-too-high-jvm-old-gen-percent-100-not-crash/74582)/[6.5s], total [6.2s]/[17.2h], memory
> [3.8gb]->[2.8gb]/[3.8gb], all_pools {[young]
> [1gb]->[165.2mb]/[1gb]}{[survivor] [111mb]->[0b]/[136.5mb]}{[old]
> [2.6gb]->[2.6gb]/[2.6gb]}

You can look at the [reference](http://discuss.elastic.co/t/2-3-3-heap-used-too-high-jvm-old-gen-percent-100-not-crash/74582) for more information.

Comment: How much RAM do you have on each physical node?

Comment: can u provide your indexing script ? you may have circular references